# How to add default values to Joomla subform fields?

Tags: joomla-3.x, xml

CMS Joomla has a standard subform field type. How to fill in the default values in it?

Field code in XML:

```
<field name="field-name" type="subform"
formsource="exampleform.xml" multiple="true"
label="Subform Field" description="Subform Field Description" />
```

Code exampleform.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form>
    <field name="example_text" type="text" label="Example Text" />
    <field name="example_textarea" type="textarea" label="Example Textarea" />
</form>
```

Can't find the answer in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for joining and asking a question Alexander.  Please take our [tour] to earn your first badge.  You may also edit your profile to tell the community a bit about yourself, your work, your Joomla experience, etc.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type

> **default** (optional) (not translatable) is the default value.

```
<field name="mytextvalue" type="text" default="Some text" label="Enter some text" description="" size="10" />
```

```
default="Some text"
```

Comment: Ok, but the form above has an attribute multiple="true" how to set for multiple lines of a form

Comment: Setting the default in exampleform.xml should load the default each time it triggers a multiple instance of the form. If you don't want the default value to be saved in the database, note that you can also use hint to show placeholder text.